# Ctrl + Z not working to exit while loop

Tags: c++, windows, eof

I've been looking around and trying a whole a bunch ways, but cannot for the life of me get Ctrl z to exit the console. Here is my code, can some one point me in the right direction:

This is on Windows.

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    Stack *stack = new Stack();
    while (cin >> s)
    {
        if (cin)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)s.length(); i++)
            {
                stack->push(s[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            {
                cout << stack->top();;
                stack->pop();
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
    } 
    stack->~Stack();
    delete stack;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman: ought to be Windows, but the OP should confirm.

Comment: Why are you calling the destructor twice? Also, the `if(cin)` seems redundant (`while (cin >> s)` already tests `cin`) and possibly a bug.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to signal EOF. On Linux, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. On either system you need to press it at the beginning of the line (i.e., after hitting enter).

By the way, there's no need to call destructors explicitly. Get rid of this line:

```
stack->~Stack();
```

In fact, it'd be better if you got rid of the `new` and `delete` altogether. Those smell like Java-isms. In C++ you don't have to always use `new` to create new objects. The more basic syntax is to write:

```
Stack stack;
```

That will create a `Stack` object and call the default no-arg constructor. The object will be automatically destructed when `main()` exits, so you don't need a `delete` or an explicit destructor invocation.

Finally, the `if (cin)` check is redundant. The `while` loop already checks that a string was read.

```
while (cin >> s)
{
    if (cin)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented my own stack class, does that make a difference when calling new/delete?

Comment: Okay So I made all the edits minus the new/delete(I'll do that later) and now it works. I swear at one point I had this very same configuration and it gave me some weird error with appending.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using built-in stack so you don't need to use **.->** and there is no need of **if(cin)** either as  **while (cin >> s)** is check is exertion stream has reached the end or not.Here is the correct code.

```
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
     string s;
     stack <string> st;

     while (cin >> s)
     {
            st.push(s);
            cout << st.top();;

            st.pop();
            cout << endl;

      }

     st.~stack();

     return 0;
```

}

Comment: Remove that `st.~stack()` call. The only bits you got right were already written by John in 2014.